# cant understand this function

Tags: vb.net, function, encryption, this

```
Public Function encrypt(ByVal message As Byte(), ByVal password As String) As Byte()

    Dim passarr As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password)

    Randomize()

    Dim rand As Integer = Int((255 - 0 + 1) * Rnd()) + 1
    Dim outarr(message.Length) As Byte
    Dim u As Integer

    For i As Integer = 0 To message.Length - 1
        outarr(i) += (message(i) Xor passarr(u)) Xor rand
        If u = password.Length - 1 Then u = 0 Else u = u + 1
    Next

    outarr(message.Length) = 112 Xor rand
    Return outarr

End Function
```

Questions I want to ask:

1. `getbytes(password)` its already declared as string ...why would you want to get bytes!!
2. what is the role of `message` here?
3. what are `rand` and `outarr` doing to `message`?
4. `outarr(message.Length) = 112 Xor rand` - I cannot understand this

Comment: You should mark this as homework if its the case.

Answer (score 0):

The function is encrypting a string.  Since it is performing arithmetic calculations on the message, you need a byte represenation (so you can do the arithmetics on the bytes).

`outarr` is the array of bytes that is the result of the encryption.  The encryption is based on a random value `rand`, which is an integer between 0 and 255.

The `112 xor rand` part, I believe, is there to be able to get the random number back from the encrypted code (by knowing the "secret" value 112)

Comment: in addition to what Attila said: In case you don't know what BitOperators are, you can look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx